# How to calculate cyclic permutation of an array?

Tags: matlab, math

how to calculate the cyclic permutation of an array easy [ 1 2 3 4 ] in matlab . Is there any function which can directly compute circular permutation in matlab .

Comment: Do you want a matrix with all circular permutations, or just a single (random?) circular permutation?

Comment: @LuisMendo I want all the cyclic permutations

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming by cyclic permutation you mean [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularPermutation.html) (*`1 2 3 4` is considered to be the same permutation as its cyclic shift `2 3 4 1`; you want all permutations that are different to any cyclic shift of each other*):

One possible approach would be to generate all permutations, identify those that are circularly equal, and keep only one from each group. That could be done keeping only those permutations that begin with a given index, for example 1. It follows that the problem can be solved by generating all permutations of elements 2, 3, ... and attaching element 1 in front:

```
x = [ 1 2 3 4 ]; %// data

p = perms(x(2:end)); %// generate all permutations of x(2), x(3), ...
p = [ repmat(x(1),size(p,1),1) p ]; %// attach x(1) in front of each permutation
```

In this example, the result is:

```
p =
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     4     3
     1     3     2     4
     1     3     4     2
     1     4     2     3
     1     4     3     2
```

---

Or, if you mean [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicPermutation.html) (*you want to generate all permutations that are cyclic shifts of each other: `1 2 3 4`, `2 3 4 1`, etc; something like `1 3 2 4` is not allowed*):

```
x = [ 1 2 3 4 ]; %// data

n = numel(x);
ii = mod(bsxfun(@plus, 1:n, (0:n-1).')-1, n) + 1;
p = x(ii);
```

Result:

```
p =
     1     2     3     4
     2     3     4     1
     3     4     1     2
     4     1     2     3
```

Comment: @Deepesh: Which solution worked for what you needed? The first or the second?

Answer (score 1):

Does `circshift` do what you need?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **circshift** to shift the array elements in a circle. Then always pick the same value of the array:

```
A=(1:5)';
P = A(1);

P = 
    1

Y = circshift(A,1);
P = A(1);

P =
    5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `toeplitz` matrix:

```
%// Some random data
A = randi(100,[1 n]);

%// all circular shifts to the right
A(toeplitz(1:numel(A), [1 numel(A):-1:2]))

%// all circular shifts to the left
A(rot90(toeplitz(1:numel(A), [1 numel(A):-1:2])))
```

Probably not the fastest, but nice to know about :)